# How is the Heap data structure useful?

Tags: data-structures, heap

Now that we have Red Black trees and AVL trees, it means that inserts and deletes take log(N) time. (We also note that find_min() would take log(N) time).

Comparing these to heap, we have same complexities. However the above mentioned trees are BST so we can search in log(N) there. All in all I don't understand how heaps can be useful?

Comment: Why would the mechanism for search have any bearing on the usefulness of heaps?  Seems like you're conflating performance with utility.

Comment: No search is additional property of BST. So they can do all that a heap can do plus something...that is what I wanted to say.

Comment: OK.  So why would that make a heap useless?  Your logic fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A heap is always perfectly balanced.  A Red Black tree has a bound on how unbalanced it can be, but it will still often be less than perfectly balanced.  While this won't affect the Big O value of the operations, it doesn't mean that there isn't a performance difference; there's a *very* wide range of possible performance among any given Big O value, and improvements within that range are still very often useful in practical application.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're talking about [this Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.

Comment: @Servy Ok so you mean that although both are log(N) one might be 2 log(N) and one might be 10log(N). Am I getting it right?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty The differences would be more complex than just a constant multiplier, but yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: @Servy Ok thanks for the answer...but I would like to know some more examples of such differences...any pdf will also do. Thanks.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty: What?

Comment: @Servy What I mean is that what kind of performance  difference can occur? Some examples might help.

Comment: This answer isn't correct, but it's already been accepted so I won't bother posting my own. The correct answer is that "a heap can be used to find the minimum element of a set in constant time".

Comment: @gardenhead As per my understanding, we only perform `contains` on Set, whether element exist or not. Union/Intersection/Complement are performed using `contains`. Did you use Set to find minimum element? I would maintain a sorted linked list, if that is the only operation you perform